# Call to a member function refreshPrice() on null Laravel version 8.83.27

Tags: laravel

I got this problem when I run a trial on my app. Does anyone know how could I fix it?

##### `app/Http/Controllers/SubscriptionController.php:146`

```php
    return view('subscription.billingInformation', [
        'invoice' => $invoice,
        'billingAddress' => $billingAddress,
    ]);
}

public function payment(Request $request)
{
    // Get current customer
    $customer = $request->user()->customer;

    // get unpaid invoice
    $invoice = $customer->invoices()->unpaid()->where('uid', '=', $request->invoice_uid)->first();

    // always update invoice price fron plan
    $invoice->refreshPrice();

    // no unpaid invoice found
    if (!$invoice) {
        // throw new \Exception('Can not find unpaid invoice with id:' . $request->invoice_uid);
        // just redirect to index
        return redirect()->action('SubscriptionController@index');
    }

    // nếu đang có pending transaction thì luôn show màn hình pending
    if ($invoice->getPendingTransaction()) {
        return view('subscription.pending', [
            'invoice' => $invoice,
        ]);
    }
```

it happens when a new subscriber confirms the offline payment then refresh the page or click on any button on the user front end.

It shows once then the user can use it normally, however it makes the feeling of not comfortable because of error code.

Please tell me what is that problem and how to fix it, thanks

Comment: Hey, you do not need to share `vendor` files, as they are known by us, it is Laravel source code. Please, share your error inside the question, because just reading the title, you can miss it

Comment: Please post your Invoice model file. That has a function called RefreshPrice

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that `refreshPrice` actually exists as a method for that model:

This error simply means that `$invoice` is null for whatever reason. Without knowing more logic -- it is still good advice that you should add some error checking around that method call.

```
if ($invoice) {
  $invoice->refreshPrice();
}
```

You'll want to investigate the logic further if `$invoice` was not supposed to be null, but, since you mentioned user navigation, it is probably just that the the data was stale on navigation (like a user refreshing).